# Shopify search for related products is not returning similar tagged products

Tags: shopify, liquid, liquid-layout

I have a custom module that returns the first 4 related products by tag. It works on ALMOST products except two tags and I can't figure out why. Excluding variants , there are only 108 products site wide. I am displaying the product tag right above the module for you to see as well.

Sample product page with working tag (PowerChairs)
https://www.gallantmedicalsupply.com/collections/power-chairs/products/compass-sport-power-chair

Sample product page with non-working tag (Walkers)
https://www.gallantmedicalsupply.com/products/walk_002

[image]

```
{% assign product = product %}
{% assign current_tags = product.tags %}
{% assign all_products = collections.all.products %}

<div  class="container custom-related-product">
  <section>
    <div>
      {% if section.settings.product_recommendations_heading != blank %}
        <div class="twelve{% unless settings.borders_enable %} bottompad{% endunless %}">
          <h2 class="text-center">{{ section.settings.product_recommendations_heading }}</h2>        
        
{% echo current_tags %}
        
        </div>
      {% endif %}
{% assign related_products = 0 %}    
      <div class="product-loop center">
          
        {% for similar_product in all_products %}
          {% if similar_product.handle != product.handle %}
            {% for current_product_tag in product.tags %}
              {% if similar_product.tags contains current_product_tag %}
                {%  render 'product.loop', product: similar_product, block_width: 'three' %}
{% assign related_products = related_products | plus: 1 %}
                {% break %}
              {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
{% if related_products == 4 %}
{% break %}
{% endif %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

        
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: I have two questions:
=> First, when it doesn't work, whats the value or related_products at the end of the loop? Is it 0?
=> Second, did you  check that there is a collection assigned?

Comment: Great question. Yes the number is 0 at the end of the loop. I added echo at the end of the script to show you. I'm not using collections but tags. For the example below, the tag is Walkers

https://www.gallantmedicalsupply.com/collections/rollators-walkers/products/walk_002

Comment: It means that none product was found matching your criterias in the first 50 products (limit of the loop) in the "all products" collection. How many products in the store?

Comment: That explains it. I have 108. I would use collection to do the loop except I have an ALL products collection which would result in the same issue.

Comment: I was about to propose a solution but saw you solved it ;)! Great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the loop limit of 50 products. I filtered the all.products by collection first (excluding all collection and current product) and then iterating to render.

```
{% if collection == null or collection.handle == 'frontpage' or collection.handle == 'all' %}
{% assign found_a_collection = false %}
{% for c in product.collections %}
  {% echo c %}
  {% if found_a_collection == false and c.handle != 'frontpage' and c.handle != 'all-products' and c.all_products_count > 1 %}
    {% assign found_a_collection = true %}
    {% assign collection = c %}
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}



  <div  class="container custom-related-product">
    <section>
           
      <div>

        {% if section.settings.product_recommendations_heading != blank %}
        <div class="twelve{% unless settings.borders_enable %} bottompad{% endunless %}">
          <h2 class="text-center">{{ section.settings.product_recommendations_heading }}</h2>
        </div>
        {% endif %}

        <div class="product-loop center">
        {% for similar_product in collection.products %}
          {% if similar_product.handle != product.handle %}
            {%  render 'product.loop', product: similar_product, block_width: 'three' %}
            {% assign related_products = related_products | plus: 1 %}
            {% if related_products == 4 %}
              {% break %}
            {% endif %}
          {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        </div>
        
      </div>

    </section>
  </div>
```